# Hoverable menu dropdown without border between trigger and content

Tags: html, css, sass

I try to make a hoverable menu with the following requirements:

- If an item in the list is hovered the content section is shown on the right.
- If an item in the list is hovered the border color of the item and content is changed. The border between item and content will be hidden.

Example is here:
[image]

My code is available here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jvk8zzqvz9

The problem is there are showed some ugly artefacts when I zoom in the browser. Maybe that my approach is wrong and there is a better way how to do it. Here are the artefacts which I mean:

[image]
[image]

My code is here:

HTML:

```html
<ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item has-dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                        <div class="menu-content">
                            <a href="">Hover me!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <div>Zde je nějaký obsah.</div>
                        <div>Zde taktéž</div>
                        <div>Hola hola.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item has-dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                        <div class="menu-content">
                            <a href="">Hover me!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        Zde je obsah dropdownu.
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item has-dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                        <div class="menu-content">
                            <a href="">Hover me!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <div>Zde je nějaký obsah.</div>
                        <div>Zde taktéž</div>
                        <div>Hola hola.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

SCSS:

```css
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;

    .menu-content {
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .menu-item {
        &.has-dropdown {
            position: relative;

            &:hover {
                .dropdown-content {
                    transition-delay: 0.25s;
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                .dropdown-trigger {
                    transition-delay: 0.25s;
                    border: 1px solid green;

                    &::after {
                        transition-delay: 0.25s;
                        visibility: visible;
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        &:not(:last-child) > .dropdown-trigger {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .dropdown-trigger {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
            &::after {
                content: '';
                transition: all 0s linear;
                visibility: hidden;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                width: 1px + 2px;
                background-color: white;
                margin-left: -1px;
                z-index: 20;
            }
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            transition: all 0s linear;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            border: 1px solid green;
            margin-left: -1px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: auto;
            left: 100%;
            min-width: 25rem;
            padding: 1rem;
            z-index: 19;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me how to achieve the result without showed artefacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the hack of the pseudo element, I will use border and make the right one of the element to be white with a higher `z-index` to cover the non needed one of the dropdown. I will also add another rule to hide to the top border of the next element.

You will notice the use of a gradient to simulate the white right border. I used it to avoid the bad effect that you will see when you zoom if you use the right border.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}
.menu .menu-content {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.menu .menu-item.has-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.menu .menu-item.has-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition:0s opacity 0.8s;
}
.menu .menu-item.has-dropdown:hover .dropdown-trigger {
  border-color: green;
  /**/
  border-right-width:0;
  /* try border-right-color:#fff and you will have the same effect
     but a small glitch when zooming
  */  
  background-size:1px 100%;
  transition:0s all 0.8s;
    
  position:relative;
  z-index:20;
}
.menu .menu-item.has-dropdown:hover + * .dropdown-trigger {
  border-top-color:green;
  transition:0s border-top-color 0.8s;
}

.menu .menu-item:not(:last-child) > .dropdown-trigger {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu .menu-item .dropdown-trigger {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right/0px 100% no-repeat;
}

.menu .menu-item .dropdown-content {
  transition: all 0s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  left: 100%;
  min-width: 25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 19;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item has-dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-trigger">
        <div class="menu-content"><a href="">Hover me!</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item has-dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-trigger">
        <div class="menu-content"><a href="">Hover me!</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">Zde je obsah dropdownu.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item has-dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-trigger">
        <div class="menu-content"><a href="">Hover me!</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
        <div>Content 3</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. This approach solved my needs. The last thing I do not know is how to add transition-delay into your code.

Comment: @jezikk you can simply add them back like in your code .. I removed them to make the code simplier and to focus and the relevant part of the code

Comment: Yes, but there is a problem in delay. I can not sync all parts of sections.

Comment: @jezikk can you show me the code with the added delay? I will see the issue

Comment: @jezikk no don't add as answer, put it on https://jsfiddle.net for example

Comment: Thank you. It works great, but unfortunately not for longer delay. :( https://codesandbox.io/s/jvk8zzqvz9

Comment: @jezikk this is due to the transition that is kept of the next element because I have used `all` .. check the update, I kept only border-top-color, it should be better

Comment: Yes it's almost done. One last thing is top-bottom green border which is displayed immediately if the menu is hovered. I absolutely have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @jezikk yes because this is the top-border of the next element, will find a trick ;)

Comment: I honestly didn't find the solution how to fix the problem with top-border. :(